# Thread 1 EXC_bad_instruction (code=exc_1386_invop subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode8

I have a problem with this code. Why is it giving me an error "Thread 1 EXC_bad_instruction (code=exc_1386_invop subcode=0x0)" on "let session" line?

```
import Foundation

protocol WeatherServiceDelegate{
    func setWeather(weather:Weather)
}

class WeatherService{

    var delegate: WeatherServiceDelegate?
    func getWeather(city: String){
        let path = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boston&"
        let url = URL(string: path)

        let session = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data: Data?, respone:URLResponse?,error: Error?) in
            print(">>>>>\(data)")
        }

        session.resume()
```

Comment: I think in swift 3 session is keyword so use other word for decalration

Comment: And it also gives me an Error Message "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: @Jecky I did try to change to a different words, but it still give me the same error

Comment: Wait I'll check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url Creation isn't working if you're getting "found nil while unwrapping"

Generally you should stay away from !s as much as possible and cast them with `if let` or `guard let`. In this case I'm not sure why it would be failing, but if you isolate the url creation you might be able to figure out the issue.

Comment: you are right, the URL is not working when I post this question. Thank you so much for your advice.